# renormalization - free energy density scaling

Tags: renormalization

By introduction to the renormalization theory we have started with the following Hamiltonian:

$$ H=\int d^d x [\delta m^2+k(\nabla m)^2+h m ] $$

We have assumed that $\delta$ and $h$ scale as:
$$ \delta_b= b^{y_{\delta}}\delta  $$
$$ h_b= b^{y_{h}}h  $$

By the computation of the scaling form of the free energy density we have got:
$$ f(\delta,h)=\delta^{\frac{d}{y_{\delta}}}g_f\left(\frac{h}{\delta^{\frac{y_h}{y_{\delta}}}}\right)  $$,
with $g_f(x)$ some scaling function.

I understand the calculation, I only have a problem with next assumption we make:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}  g_f(x)=const,$$
so 
$$ f(\delta) \approx \delta^{\frac{d}{y_{\delta}}} $$
for small $\delta$.

Why should this assumption make sense?

And the next question: in our lecture it was said that only critical exponents matters in which universality class our system is, in some book I have found statement that also scaling function matters. Who is right?